# How to modify style attribute via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have elements, generated by UI-framework as follows:

```
<div id="GENERATED_CONTAINER" style="position: fixed; z-index: 100; left: 368px; top: 52px; width: 545px; height: 846px;">
    <div id="GENERATED_CONTENT style="opacity: 0.1; left: 5px; top: 5px; bottom: -5px; width: 545px; height: 846px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to write a script which is to remove `width` and `height` from style attributes.

```
var elems = $("[id^='GENERATED_']");
//what should I apply now?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write `.css`

```
$("[id^='GENERATED_']").css({
  width: 'inherit', //or the value
  height: 'inherit' //or the value
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id^='GENERATED_']").css({width:0px,height:0px})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the inline style using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EricLease/omgd47gv/) of inline style being added and removed via `jQuery.css()`.